# Air condition /CONDENSATION

Tags: walls

The insulated pipe coming into our house and is inside the wall going into the article is creating condensation.  Do we need to insulate the pipe inside the wall?  The wall I currently insulated but we are finding water at the base.  Will sealing the pipes coming into the house help and if so what do we use?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the pipe should be insulated.

During normal operation of the a/c system, the pipe may be below the dew point temperature. If air comes in contact with this cold pipe, moisture from the air will condense on the pipe.